# Parametrize input datasets in kedro

Tags: python, kedro

I'm trying to move my project into a kedro pipeline but I'm struggling with the following step:

my prediction pipeline is being run by a scheduler. The scheduler supplies all the necessary parameters (dates, country codes etc.). Up until now I had a CLI which would get input parameters such as below

`python predict --date 2022-01-03 --country UK`

The code would then read the input dataset for a given date and for a given country, so the query would be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM input_data_{country}
WHERE date = {date}
```

and this would be formatted using the input variables passed in the CLI.

Important note: the code has to run on any arbitary date passed by the scheduler, and not only on "today".

How would I parametrize Kedro's data catalog using CLI arguments?

I tried the examples in the documentation of Kedro but it seems that they are mainly geared towards using templates from config in reading the data. The key issue I'm struggling with is passing CLI arguments to the data catalog and haven't found a working solution. I looked into `PartitionedDataSet` but I don't see an option to have CLI arguments as inputs there

Comment: Regarding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76962174), please undelete it and then let me know when it is undeleted. I can undownvote it, but please note the spelling (case) feedback you have received.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, here it is if anyone has a similar problem.

The key is to use a `TemplatedConfigLoader` class and insert variables into the `catalog.yml`

So with my example of country code:

```
SELECT *
FROM input_data_${country}
```

will get variables from `globals.yml`:

```
country: "UK"
```

but only if the `settings.py` are set in the following way, so that it uses the variables from the global config.

```
CONFIG_LOADER_CLASS = MyTemplatedConfigLoader # TemplatedConfigLoader
# Keyword arguments to pass to the `CONFIG_LOADER_CLASS` constructor.
CONFIG_LOADER_ARGS = {
    "globals_pattern": "*globals.yml",
}

class MyTemplatedConfigLoader(TemplatedConfigLoader):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.runtime_params:
            self._config_mapping.update(self.runtime_params)
```

Now, the variables can be overriden in terminal like this:

`kedro run --pipeline=predict --params country:US`